# Get data in a scenario in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario like this, I have TblCustomer in plsql, in that I have deptId column which has value from 1 to 7, customer and department has many to many relationship, sample records are given below

```
CustName     DeptId

Cust1         1
Cust2         5
Cust3         3
Cust1         2
Cust4         5
...............
```

I want to get records in this dept id order : 1,6,7,3,5,2,4 i am using below query for that

```
Select * from tblCust order by DECODE(DeptId,1,1,6,2,7,3,3,4,5,5,2,6,4,7)
```

till here it is fine, now i want to remove those Customername records from deptid 6 who is already there in deptid1, remove Customername records from id 7 who are already there in 6, means i want to display all customer records from DeptId 1, then all records EXCEPT DeptId 1 record from DeptId 6, then all records EXCEPT previous two records From DeptId 7 and so on.... any help please?

Comment: Have you tried Distinct on CustName, Like Select Distinct CustName from tblCust order by DECODE(DeptId,1,1,6,2,7,3,3,4,5,5,2,6,4,7)

Comment: actually i want to select entire row not just CustName, so can not use distinct, also if i am ordering it by DeptId then I have to use it in select statement, so can't use distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to spread that case through the whole DeptID spectrum (if you also want to remove those rows from dept id 3 which were occurred in deptids (1,6,7), then remove rows from deptid 5 which were occurred in deptids (1,6,7,3), then remove rows from deptid 2 which were occurred in deptids (1,6,7,3,5)...), you could use the following code with `MIN` function, grouped by `CustName`:

```
SELECT CustName, MIN(DECODE(DeptId,1,1,6,2,7,3,3,4,5,5,2,6,4,7)) as DeptId
  FROM tblCust 
 GROUP BY CustName
 ORDER BY DECODE(DeptId,1,1,6,2,7,3,3,4,5,5,2,6,4,7)
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: didn't understand what you did..:-P, but works fine, Thank you

Comment: Using the `MIN` function returns one row per `CustName`, only the row that features minimal value of `DECODE(DeptId,1,1,6,2,7,3,3,4,5,5,2,6,4,7)` for that `CustName`. I hope that explained it successfully :)

Comment: so by using decode inside MIN it will consider like this? 1 < 6 < 7 < 3 < 5 < 2 <4 :-O

Comment: Yes :) Because outside the `DECODE` function (and therefor inside the `MIN` evaluation) 6 is actually 2, 7 is 3 etc.

Comment: Hey one more small question,  i have 60+ columns in customer table and if i want to select them all i need to use all that columns after group by clause,  right?

Comment: You need to put everything in `GROUP BY` that you put in `SELECT`, outside the group functions (as `MIN` is), so the answer would be `yes` to the direct question... But, I wouldn't recommend it as it would most likely change the result of your `MIN` evaluation. `MIN` would then calculate the minimal value of `DECODE(DeptId)` among the whole `60+ column combination`, and not just among `CustName` values. I would therefor recommend using different queries for calculating `MIN` value (the query above) and for selecting other columns, by using the above query either as a subquery or some other way

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler, more elegant way, but this should also work:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tblCust 
 WHERE (  (DeptId = 6 AND CustName NOT IN (SELECT CustName
                                             FROM tblCust
                                            WHERE DeptId = 1)
           )
        OR DeptId != 6
        )
   AND (  (DeptId = 7 AND CustName NOT IN (SELECT CustName
                                             FROM tblCust
                                            WHERE DeptId IN (1, 6))
           )
        OR DeptId != 7
        )
 ORDER BY DECODE(DeptId,1,1,6,2,7,3,3,4,5,5,2,6,4,7)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: this can be a way but after this two cases i also want to remove those rows from dept id 3 which were occurred in deptids (1,6,7), then remove rows from deptid 5 which were occurred in deptids (1,6,7,3), then remove rows from deptid 2 which were occurred in deptids (1,6,7,3,5), so it will be quite long and complex query.